# Inconsistent "Page Not Found" Behaviour

Tags: python, html, django, file-not-found

I am currently working on a simple Asset Manager program in Django. In `assman.html`, there is this code snippet which deals with changing the details of an asset:

```
{%if change_form%}
<h2>Change Asset Details</h2>
<form method="POST" name='change_asset' action="{% url 'assman_handler' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if NoSuchUser %}
  <script>window.alert('No such user!')</script>
  {% endif %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="qrcode">QR Code:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qrcode" class="form-control" id="qrcode" maxlength='13' value = "{{ asset.qrcode }}" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for ="name" required>Asset Name: </label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" class='form-control' value = "{{ asset.name }}" required ></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="user_id">User:</label></td>
      <td>
        <select name="user_id">
          {%for user in users%}
            <option value="{{ user.id }}" {% if user.id == asset.user.id %}selected{% endif %}>{{ user.username }}</option> </option>
          {%endfor%}
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="checkout_date">Checkout Date:</label></td>
      <td><input type="date" name="checkout_date" class="form-control" id="checkout_date" value = "{{asset.checkout_date}}" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="location">Location:</label></td>
      <td><input name="location" class="form-control" id="location" value = "{{asset.location}}" required></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value='confirm' name='value'>Confirm Changes</button>
</form>
{%endif%}
```

This form is previously summoned by clicking the button "change" as described in this code:

```
<h2>Matched Items</h2>
{%for asset in matches%}
<li> {{asset.name}} at {{asset.location}} owned by {{asset.user}} expiring on {{asset.checkout_date}}</li>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'assman_handler' %}" style="display: inline-block;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="value" value="change" id="change-btn">
    <input type="hidden" value={{asset.id}} name='asset_id'>
  </form>
  <form method='POST' action="{% url 'assman_handler' %}" style="display: inline-block;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="delete" name='value' >
    <input type="hidden" name = "asset_id" value={{asset.id}} name='asset'>
  </form>
</li>
{%endfor%}
```

The function which is called in both instances is views.py's assman_handler():

```py
def assman_handler(request):
    print(request.POST.get('value'))
    #Setting variable values
    if request.POST.get('value') == 'change': return render(request, 'assman.html', {'users': User.objects.all(),'change_form': True, 'asset': asset, 'allass': Asset.objects.all()})
    elif request.POST.get('value') == 'confirm':
        # Behaviour for changing assets
        redirect('assman')
    elif request.POST.get('value') == 'delete':
        asset.delete()
    redirect('assman')
```

Since I added the line  `print(request.POST.get('value'))`, I know that it is run properly when "change" and "delete" are pressed, but it is not run at all when "Confirm Changes" is pressed. In that case, it simply returns this error instead:

Page not found (404)
No Asset matches the given query.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/assman_handler
Raised by:  assman.views.assman_handler

What might cause this inconsistent "Page not Found" behaviour? Additionally, how should I code it to avoid this problem? I have looked into urls.py but if it is misconfigured (it is not), the other buttons should also return a file not found. I have also checked if the `name`s and `value`s of the buttons are consistent, as that is what is looked at. However, I'm stumped.

EDIT:
The asset is fetched by this line:

```
assid = request.POST.get('asset_id')
asset = Asset.objects.get(id=assid)
```

I defined Asset in models.py:

````
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    checkout_date = models.DateField()
    qrcode = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    objects = models.Manager()
    ```
````

Comment: You don't include the part of your view where you fetch the Asset from the DB, please include it

Comment: I think I included it. Do let me know if I need to include anything more

Comment: Please show the code that defines the variable `assid` in your view. The template `assman.html` doesn't seem to have an input containing the asset id so not sure where you get it from without seeing the complete view

Comment: Right. Please check now.

Since I can't get the formatting to work, here it is:

assid = request.POST.get('asset_id')

Comment: There is no input with `name="asset_id"` in the form in `assman.html` - `request.POST.get('asset_id')` will be returning `None` since that key does not exist in the POST data

Comment: Then I should add the lines:
  <input type='hidden' value = "{{asset.id}}">